# Proving if equation is $O(\log n)$

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

How do I prove if

\begin{equation} 2\log(n^{2}\log n) = O(\log n) \end{equation}
is true?

I began by trying to find a $C$ where

\begin{equation} 2\log(n^{2}\log n) < O(\log n) \end{equation}

but I can't determine what to multiply $\log n$ by in order to make it greater than \begin{equation} 2\log(n^{2}\log n)\end{equation}

Answer (score 2):

$2\log(n^2\log(n))=4\log(n)+\log(\log(n))<5\log(n)$.

Comment: Can you explain what you did? I'm a little confused

Comment: I used the following rules of logarithms:
$\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ and $\log(a^n)=n\log(a)$.